# Multiple instances of gameObject not performing identically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

So I have three different 'bystanders' in my game world, each with an attached 'Bystander' script, and have a 'BystanderDialogue' element of my UI. The idea is that when the player comes in range of ANY of the bystanders, randomly selected text from a database is displayed, but for my script it only ever works for ONE of the bystanders.

I feel like I'm cross-referencing scripts too much or something, but I don't know. Here are the two sections of code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Bystander : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject player;
public bool speak;
public bool isPlayerNear;
public int dialogueNumber;
GameObject bystanderDialogueObject;
BystanderDialogue bystanderDialogue;


// Use this for initialization
void Awake () 
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
    bystanderDialogueObject = GameObject.Find ("BystanderDialogue");
    bystanderDialogue = bystanderDialogueObject.GetComponent<BystanderDialogue> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject == player) 
    {
        dialogueNumber = Random.Range (0, bystanderDialogue.bystanderSpeech.Length);
        speak = true;
        isPlayerNear = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject == player) 
    {
        speak = false;
        isPlayerNear = false;
    }
}
}
```

And the second one, attached to the UI object  'BystanderDialogue':

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class BystanderDialogue : MonoBehaviour {

Text text;
GameObject[] bystanderObjects;
Bystander bystander;
public string[] bystanderSpeech;
// Use this for initialization
void Awake () 
{
    text = GetComponent<Text> ();
    bystanderObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("NPC");
    foreach (GameObject bystanderObject in bystanderObjects) 
    {
        bystander = bystanderObject.GetComponent<Bystander> ();
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
        BystanderSpeak (bystander);

        if (bystander.isPlayerNear) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("New bystander!");
        }

}

void BystanderSpeak(Bystander bystander)
{
    if (bystander.speak && bystander.isPlayerNear) 
    {
        text.text = bystanderSpeech[bystander.dialogueNumber];
    }
    else if (!bystander.speak && !bystander.isPlayerNear)
    {
        text.text = "";
    }
}
}
```

I'm very sure that I'm making some elementary mistakes, so apologies. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: How many BystanderDialogue script instances should be in the scene? One for each bystander or one in total?

Comment: Just one BystanderDialogue overall to manage every instance of Bystander. That was the idea, anyway

Comment: Please use unity3d tag for such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does not make sense:

```
void Awake () 
{
    text = GetComponent<Text> ();
    bystanderObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("NPC");
    foreach (GameObject bystanderObject in bystanderObjects) 
    {
        bystander = bystanderObject.GetComponent<Bystander> ();
    }
}
```

If there are more than one bystanderObject, then you only kept the last object as reference into the `bystander` member field. You should use a collection (list or array) instead to keep all of them:

```
Bystander[] bystanders;


void Awake()
{
    bystanderObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("NPC");
    bystanders = new Bystander[bystanderObjects.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < bystanderObjects.Length; ++i)
    {
        bystander[i] = bystanderObjects[i].GetComponent<Bystander>();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** it seams that you have a misconception of how everything works in Unity between two frames. I suggest you read [Execution Order of Event Functions](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

Your `Update()` method will be completed before anything is drawn on the screen. So if you overwrite the value of `Text`, only the last written value will be displayed. In fact, you need one `Text` instance for each `bystander`.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'm slightly new to this.

However, the text is still only displayed for one of the bystanders, even putting my BystanderSpeak function into a loop in the update.

Also inserting a `Debug.Log` shows me that the `isPlayerNear` trigger works for each individually, but not the function.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the `BystanderSpeak()` function. Adding the debug to it:

`void BystanderSpeak(Bystander bystander)
 {
  if (bystander.speak && bystander.isPlayerNear) 
  {
   Debug.Log (bystanderSpeech[bystander.dialogueNumber]);
   text.text = bystanderSpeech[bystander.dialogueNumber];
  }
  else if (!bystander.speak && !bystander.isPlayerNear)
  {
   text.text = "";
  }
 }`
shows the correct text in the console, but doesn't display on the UI text.

Comment: Same issue as before: you only have one text while you need one per bystander. There is really no issue specific to unity3d here. Just basic logic mistakes.

Comment: Thanks very much, I guess I just thought I could condense things more than I actually can.